# Define global function within anonymous self-executing function?

Tags: javascript, self-executing-function

```
(function(){

  var someValue = 5;

  function myFunction(input) = {
    return someValue * input;
  };

})();
```

I have a self-executing function, that contains many things, among them at function that I would like to make global. I would typically just declare it in the global scope, but it needs to be able to reference variables that are local only to the self-executing function.

What is the best approach to making the function globally-accessible without getting rid of the self-executing function altogether (thus littering the global space with variables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the function to the global `window` object.

```
(function(){

  var someValue = 5;

  window.myFunction = function (input) {
    return someValue * input;
  };

})();
```

After the immediate function executed, you can call `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could do something like this, which has essentially the same result that ntalbs proposed.

```
 var myFunction;
 (function(){
     var someValue = 5;
     myFunction = function (input) {
         return someValue * input;
     };
 })();

console.log( myFunction( 4 ), window.myFunction ); // output: 20, function(input){return someValue * input}
```